# What happens to main queue/main thread, when a dispatch_sync is issued from main thread targeting another dispatch queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Suppose I call the method below on the main thread.  If some other thread is doing a write on the array at the time the method is called, the dispatch_sync will block.  But it is blocking on another queue (not main queue).  When this is blocked, what is the state on the main queue (method cannot move forward until the disaptch_sync returns, but is this treated like a asynchronous call on the main queue).  For e.g:  will the main queue respond to UI events?  If yes, what will happen to the state of the method call when dispatch_sync returns when the reaction to user event is happening?

```
-(id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    __block id obj;
    dispatch_sync(self.dataAccessQ, ^{
        obj = self.embeddedArray[index];
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether it's the main queue or not. Whatever queue is used to call `objectAtIndex:` will block on the `dispatch_sync` call until it completes.

If you call this code on the main queue, it blocks like any other queue. During that time, no user events will be processed. The UI will appear locked during that time. When done, the UI will again work as normal.

Comment: Using a parallel queue, other tasks in that queue can continue running.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad If `objectAtIndex:` is called from a concurrent queue, and the concurrent queue is using multiple threads, then the thread used to process the `objectAtIndex:` method will block while `dispatch_sync` is used. Other threads (if any) used by the concurrent queue will not be affected. But the main queue is a serial queue so none of this applies.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy  So, to conclude if I am creating a thread-safe array, it looks like there is not much I can do other than design such that no writes take too long.

Comment: That would be a whole different discussion. I'd do some research on thread-safe arrays and if needed, post a new question specific to whatever issues you have with that.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy. Will do.  Any pointers to a good design of thread-safe array?

Comment: @rmaddy Exactly. But you wrote *It doesn't matter whether it's the main queue or not. Whatever queue is used to call objectAtIndex: will block on the dispatch_sync call until it completes.* It matters.

Answer (score 1):

No, the main queue is akin of blocked, too.

The main queue is bound to the main thread. Every thread can execute one and only one control flow at a time. If any code is executed on the main thread, no other code can be executed.

Therefore waiting for the result of an operation subscripted to another queue will block the waiting thread. (Not a parallel Q!) This is why we have completion handlers.

Instead of returning an object, add a parameter for a completion handler to your method and call that inside the block at the end.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to create a thread-safe array.  So, I need to over-ride objectAtIndex and can't add parameters.  Any workarounds for this case (like the completion block approach)?

Comment: You should really think again about having a thread-safe array. It is like atomic properties no solution for most of the problems with concurrent execution. Usually you need an object managing the content of the array and a queue that allows you to serialize code that is wider than the simple access.